# invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'QModbusClient'

Tags: c++, qt

Доброго времени суток! Я новичок, не судите строго. Подскажите пожалуйста, что делаю не так. Использую qt 5.6.0.

```
#include <QModbusClient>
...

void MainWindow::getDeviceData(){
        ...
        QModbusClient *client = new QModbusClient(this);
        ...
}
```

При сборке выдаёт ошибку: "invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'QModbusClient'"

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QModbusClient` – абстрактный класс, поэтому нельзя создать объект этого класса. Используйте [наследников](http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.6/qmodbusclient.html) (поле `Inherited By`): [QModbusRtuSerialMaster](http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.6/qmodbusrtuserialmaster.html) или [QModbusTcpClient](http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.6/qmodbustcpclient.html).

Для вашего кода это будет, например:

```
QModbusClient *client = new QModbusRtuSerialMaster(this);

// Или так:
// QModbusRtuSerialMaster *client = new QModbusRtuSerialMaster(this);
```